# Date as an input parameter to Webi report

Tags: business-objects, webi

I am trying to create a WebI report with just a single input date, from a prompt, and then get n time slices, weeks or months, after it(max of 12).

For example param_input = 1/1/12 and also there is an input of 'n'.

I thought I would try a query filter on the weekly time slices and then do a
`between param_input and RelativeDate(param_input, 7*n)`.

But the query builder isn't liking the dynamically-created date.

Is there anyway to dynamically get that second date or do I just need to have two dates provided?

Or alternatively is there a way to just pull down 12 slices and just filter down to the first n values?

Comment: Is `n` prompted as well?

Comment: Yup... I'm prompting for what type of slice is wanted, and the number of periods they wanted

Answer (score 0):

you should create a new object in the universe (if you use MS SQL)

```
 [Date+7]=DATEADD(@prompt('Period','A',{'Day','Month','Year'},
mono,constrained,persistent),7,@prompt('Enter date:','D',,mono,free,persistent)).
```

and in the report add filter:

[Date] between UserInputWithText_EnterDate and [Date+7](from the universe)